# Can't start gdb over ssh

Tags: tramp, gdb, gud

I am able to open a remote C source file using tramp (via ssh). However, when I try to debug it using

```
M-x gdb
gdb -i=mi /ssh:localhost#8022:/usr/bin/httrack
```

I get

```
Current directory is /ssh:localhost#8022:/usr/bin/
Error: you did not specify -i
Debugger exited abnormally with code 127
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I didn't have gdb installed on the remote side.